# Calling an instance javascript method from Java(JSP)?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a JSP file with a calendar function using the JQuery Frontier Calendar. I already have it implemented and every time I add an appointment it saves it to my Database. My problem is that how can I retrieve the data?

In order to add an appointment I used the following predefined function:

```
jfcalplugin.addAgendaItem("#mycal",title,startDateObj,endDateObj,false,{internal_id: responseText,calendario : calendario},{backgroundColor : background,foregroundColor : "#000000"});
```

Where it's already initialize using:

```
var jfcalplugin = $("#mycal").jFrontierCal({
        date: new Date(),
        dayClickCallback: myDayClickHandler,
        agendaClickCallback: myAgendaClickHandler,
        applyAgendaTooltipCallback: myApplyTooltip,
        dragAndDropEnabled: false
    }).data("plugin");
```

It can't send an AJAX response with all the elements since It would be plain text, neither I can replace the jfcalplugin since I will lose the instantiated object. Is their any way to send some `<script>` tags and execute them? I´m using 
Java to connect to my Database through JSP.

Comment: The part about not being able to send ajax doesn't make sense. Should be simple to make request and in success callback add the new item to plugin. What does `how can I retrieve data` mean?

Comment: How can I execute something that is returned as plain text? What I mean was can I dynamically add appointments to my calendar using that specific line

Comment: Nothing to execute. You have enough data to create object in plugin. Send that to server, insert in database, get new id and return data as json. Inside success callback use response data to call `addAgendaItem`

Comment: Sorry didn´t quite catch that, what do I send? The var jfcalpluging as BLOB?

Comment: All i am suggesting is within each change you send ajax request to update server. Using json which gets changed to javascript object when it is returned

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding whatever the specifc flow process problem you are having is. Question is a bit confusing

Comment: Yeah I know, I didn´t really knew how to explain myself. No the problem relies on how to load the content not how to save it.

Comment: Make ajax call and initialize plugin inside success callback so you can pass data into it

Comment: Yeah I got it, I used the AJAX datatype "script" in order to execute the code. Thanks